# Sorting a table with dynamically shown columns in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to make a table which has sorting as well as a button to select which columns are to be displayed.
Both these features work when used alone but fail when I try to use them together.

**JS**

```js
angular.module('test', []);

angular.module("test").controller("sessionCtrl", sessionCtrl);


function sessionCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.testvar= "HELLO";
  vm.sortType = 'name';
  vm.sortReverse = false;

  vm.columnVisiblity = {

    name: true,
    specification: true,
    type: true,
  };
  vm.TableData = [{

    name: "2017/03/01-14",
    specification: "IDB-idb-1wk",
    type: "Full"

  }, {

    name: "2017/03/01-17",
    specification: "Set-04",
    type: "Full"
  }, {
    name: "2017/03/04-11",
    specification: "IDB-idb-1wk",
    type: "Full"
  }];


}
```

**HTML**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="sessionCtrl as vm">
  {{vm.testvar}}
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th ng-click="vm.sortType='name'; vm.sortReverse=!vm.sortReverse" ng-if="vm.columnVisiblity.name">NAME
        </th>
        <th ng-click="vm.sortType='specification'; vm.sortReverse=!vm.sortReverse" ng-if="vm.columnVisiblity.specification">SPECIFICATION
        </th>
        <th ng-click="vm.sortType='type'; vm.sortReverse=!vm.sortReverse" ng-if="vm.columnVisiblity.type">TYPE
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.TableData | orderBy:vm.sortType:vm.sortReverse">

        <td ng-if="vm.columnVisiblity.name">{{item.name}}</td>
        <td ng-if="vm.columnVisiblity.specification">{{item.specification}}</td>
        <td ng-if="vm.columnVisiblity.type">{{item.type}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
  <a href="#" ng-model="vm.columnVisibility.name" ng-click="vm.columnVisiblity.name=!vm.columnVisiblity.name">TOGGLE NAME</a>

  <a href="#" ng-model="vm.columnVisibility.specification" ng-click="vm.columnVisiblity.specification=!vm.columnVisiblity.specification">TOGGLE SPECIFICATION</a>

  <a href="#" ng-model="vm.columnVisibility.type" ng-click="vm.columnVisiblity.type=!vm.columnVisiblity.type">TOGGLE TYPE</a>
</body>
```

Basically I'm making a table whose columns are visible on the basis of the `columnVisibility` object. 
And I'm using orderby filter to sort the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('test', []);

angular.module("test").controller("sessionCtrl", sessionCtrl);


function sessionCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.testvar= "HELLO";
  vm.sortType = 'name';
  vm.sortReverse = false;

  vm.columnVisiblity = {

    name: true,
    specification: true,
    type: true,
  };
  vm.TableData = [{

    name: "2017/03/01-14",
    specification: "IDB-idb-1wk",
    type: "Full"

  }, {

    name: "2017/03/01-17",
    specification: "Set-04",
    type: "Full"
  }, {
    name: "2017/03/04-11",
    specification: "IDB-idb-1wk",
    type: "Full"
  }];


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="sessionCtrl as vm">
  {{vm.testvar}}
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th ng-click="vm.sortType='name'; vm.sortReverse=!vm.sortReverse" ng-if="vm.columnVisiblity.name">NAME
        </th>
        <th ng-click="vm.sortType='specification'; vm.sortReverse=!vm.sortReverse" ng-if="vm.columnVisiblity.specification">SPECIFICATION
        </th>
        <th ng-click="vm.sortType='type'; vm.sortReverse=!vm.sortReverse" ng-if="vm.columnVisiblity.type">TYPE
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.TableData | orderBy:vm.sortType:vm.sortReverse">

        <td ng-if="vm.columnVisiblity.name">{{item.name}}</td>
        <td ng-if="vm.columnVisiblity.specification">{{item.specification}}</td>
        <td ng-if="vm.columnVisiblity.type">{{item.type}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
  <a href="#" ng-model="vm.columnVisiblity.name" ng-click="vm.columnVisiblity.name=!vm.columnVisiblity.name">TOGGLE NAME</a>

  <a href="#" ng-model="vm.columnVisiblity.specification" ng-click="vm.columnVisiblity.specification=!vm.columnVisiblity.specification">TOGGLE SPECIFICATION</a>

  <a href="#" ng-model="vm.columnVisibility.type" ng-click="vm.columnVisiblity.type=!vm.columnVisiblity.type">TOGGLE TYPE</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The typo was when I typed the code for SO, my parent code is big so I tried to make a smaller snippet. Fixed the typo in the question. My original code doesnt have the typo

Comment: No, the issue isn't fixed. In my parent code, I've extensively checked for typos. The issue is that while addition and deletion of column works okay, the sorting isn't working. But if I remove the columnVisiblity part, sorting works fine again.

Comment: @ChaoticTwist please can see the demo. The sorting is working fine

Comment: I realized that too. I guess there's some other issue over there unrelated to this part. My code is a part of a larger application, so it could be other components, I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @ChaoticTwist :-)

Comment: I use $scope in my parent code instead of using "controller as" , would that make difference?

Comment: @ChaoticTwist It will not make any difference. You can find detailed explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Answer (score 2):

Problem is `<a href="#" ng-model="vm.columnVisibility.name" ng-click="vm.columnVisibility.name=!vm.columnVisibility.name">TOGGLE NAME</a>` here spelling of `columnVisibility` doesnt match with that in controller

```
 vm.columnVisiblity = {

    name: true,
    specification: true,
    type: true,
  };
```

It is a typing mistake, correct the spelling and it will work

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/m7a74L8f/

Comment: The typo was when I typed the code for SO, my parent code is big so I tried to make a smaller snippet. Fixed the typo in the question.
My original code doesnt have the typo.

Comment: If you fixed the typo, then code is working fine, you can check the fiddle. It is sorting as well as toggling column

Comment: In my parent code, I've extensively checked for typos. The issue is that while addition and deletion of column works okay, the sorting isn't working. But if I remove the columnVisiblity part, sorting works fine again.

My parent code uses checkboxes instead of hyperlinks for column visiblity, would that make any difference?
(I know that the fiddle works correctly, still can't figure out the issue)

Comment: It won't make any difference if you use checkbox also, because on ng-click you are giving the same code, i am feeling there is no problem in this part of code, something else is messing up the code.

Comment: I figure the same. It is a large application. I'll look into what else could be the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: I use $scope in my parent code instead of using "controller as" , would that make difference? –

Comment: As far as i know It won't make a difference.